# Pandas - How to Extract Headers Which Are Contained Within Each Row?

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner with Pandas and I have a large dataset in an archaic format which I would like to wrangle into Pandas format. The data looks like this:

```
    0       1       2       3       4       5         ...
0   ì       8=xx    9=00    35=8    49=YY   56=073    ...
1   8=xx    9=00    35=8    49=YY   56=073  34=10715  ...
2   8=xx    9=00    35=8    49=YY   56=073  34=10716  ...
...
```

The column headers are separated by "=" with header on the left and field on the right. Hence the data should look like this:

```
    8   9   35  49   56     34   ...
0   xx  00  8   YY   073    107  ...
1   xx  00  8   YY   073    107  ...
2   xx  00  8   YY   073    107  ...
...
```

Each row has a different number of columns and there may be some repetition per row, for example, **8=xx** may occur multiple times per row. I would like to create a new column (eg. 8_x, 8_y, ...) each time this happens. I have tried to formulate a for/iterrows() loop to iterate through each row but not sure how I can separate a string and set the header at one go.

I've tried to look for a similar issue on the site but no success so far. Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: Adding in the code I used to parse the initial raw data into the format in the first table.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('File.dat', sep='\n',nrows = 2, header=None, encoding = "ANSI")  
df = df[0].str.split('<SPECIAL CHAR.>', expand=True)
```

Comment: what does `ì` represent ?

Comment: What's the original format of the data, before you create a dataframe out of it?

Comment: @Datanovice : The ì is a garbage header and should be discarded...

Comment: @Roy2012 the original data was stored in a "dat" file. It's a plaintext that Notepad++ has identified as ANSI encoding.

Comment: Could you please attach a piece of the original data? As I wrote above, the easiest way is probably to parse the data before it’s read into the pandas data frame.

Comment: @Roy2012 sure, here is an excerpt. It's a continuous stream of text, where each new row begins with the same entry: **8=ABJQ** . However the "garbage" character separator cannot be pasted in this excerpt so I'm not sure that this is very helpful.
 `Ã¬8=ABJQ1=55506535=801=QJP56=57330=157=57315103=Y177=75115635-77:55:51.11537=75115671157536711=11110151801=111101518053=7008=FPW71N573151007=J057=3607=J057=0007=J057=317=11155=031=0378=51=55611563108=575577=11767=NM50=738=755505=700=7.5551=60371=I151=510=565=75115635-77:55:55.555717=Y15=157Ã«`

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful - this is how the dat file looks when opened in Notepad++: https://imgur.com/a/mZvuIum

Comment: @rzwa - see my answer below. Let me know if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above in one of the comments on the original post, the 'right' way to deal with this would be to parse the data before it's in a dataframe. That being said, once the data is in a dataframe you can use the following code:

```
rows = []

def parse_row(row):
    d = {}
    for item in row[1]:
        if type(item) != str or "=" not in item:
            continue # ignore this item
        [col_name, val] = item.split("=")
        if col_name in d:
            inx = 0
            while f"{col_name}_{inx}" in d: 
                inx += 1
            col_name = f"{col_name}_{inx}"
            print("new colname is {col_name}")
        d[col_name] = val
    return d

for row in df.iterrows():
    rows.append(parse_row(row))

pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

I tested it with the following input:

```
    0       1       2       3       4       5         
0   ì       8=xx    9=00    35=8    49=YY   56=073    
1   8=xx    9=00    35=8    49=YY   56=073  34=10715  
2   8=xx    9=00    35=8    49=YY   8=zz    34=10716
```

This is the output:

```
    8   9 35  49   56     34  8_0
0  xx  00  8  YY  073    NaN  NaN
1  xx  00  8  YY  073  10715  NaN
2  xx  00  8  YY  NaN  10716   zz
```

Comment: thanks! The code works for the snippet. However, when I run it on the larger data set, I get the following error -  
`File "<ipython-input-100-7673817e0771>", line 21, in <module>
    rows.append(parse_row(row))

  File "<ipython-input-100-7673817e0771>", line 8, in parse_row
    if "=" not in item:

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable`

Comment: If I convert the following into .str as follows `if "=" not in item.str():` then this is the error I receive instead: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: @rzwa - updated the solution to ignore items which are not strings: "if type(item) != str or "=" not in item:"

Answer (score 2):

If the original .dat file is in a plain text format like one of the comment says it can be easily transformed into the CSV format:

1. Open the .dat file in your favorite text editor that support regular expressions.
2. Copy the first line and remove all occurrences of '=[^,]+' to create the header with column names.
3. From the 2nd line onward remove all occurrences of '[^,]=' to preserve the cell values.
4. Save the CSV file and open in Python with `pd.read_csv(...)`.

This way every time you load the CSV chances are Pandas will guess the data format in each column correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in one of the comments on the original post, the 'right' way to deal with this would be to parse the data before it's in a dataframe

Comment: Please state a code snippet, if you would like our answer get accepted.